# Can employer see your posting content on a public site when using their network on their hardware

Tags: network, surveillance

Can the employer identify you as the person that posted on a website (you logged onto the system using their computer) if the computer is replaced by a new one?

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged this as "passwords". Were passwords supposed to come into the question?

Comment: Why does a change in computers come into play? Are you interested in them tracking you down or the computer you used?

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad and thus I can only provide a more or less broad answer instead of something specific to your unknown actual use case:
If the employer has or had access to the old computer or if you used the computer while being in the company network then all the necessary information might be available to the employer. This does not actually mean that they will be available in all use cases and that the employer actually has the knowledge and time (or money) to track you and your postings down, but only that the chance is very high that the employer could do it if he actually cared that much.